# Enter username in table automatically on update phpymadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table with multiple columns on phpmyadmin (MYSQL).

There are only 3 I am interested in for this question.

The first column is a decision column - think "yes" or "no".

The second column is the ID of the agent who entered the decision.

The final column is the current timestamp which is updated when the decision column is updated.

Since users log on with a username and password, is there a way to automatically update the ID column with the username when they update the decision column?

Comment: In which way do people log on? Via phpmyadmin? Via some script? Via http-authentification? In other words, how gets the system known of the username?

Comment: @syck they log on via phpmyadmin

Comment: Sorry for that, but I see no possibility how that can be done. AFAIK the only data which can be automatically written is the current timestamp. However, looking into the database logs (if you have logging enabled) may give you the information you need.

Comment: @syck - is there anyway to do this? If I have them log in differently or something?

Comment: Database logs have to be enabled in database configuration. Then you may be able to see whether which change happened when by which user.